# Vue.js: event after v-for is done

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I am trying to build a simple chat app with Vue.js. My problem is that the message area needs to scroll to the bottom when a new message is written.

I looping through the messages with v-for directive. Is there an event when v-for has updated the DOM?

I have made it so that the message area div listens to component's message-array. I tried so that in the same function that I am appending the message to the array, it would set the message area div's scrollTop to 99999. But the problem is that v-for is not done updating the DOM, so it will not scroll to the correct point.

Comment: I don't know if there is a hook or event after a `v-for` loop is done, but you can do like in every for, comparing the actual index to check if it is the last iteration? something like `$index === array.length - 1` and bind that to a class or style to make your div scroll?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I had a similar issue but I took a different approach using the `vue.nextTick()`. I needed to be sure the `v-for` had finished rendering as the component will not re-render immediately, It will update on the next “tick” when the queue is empty.

```
Vue.component('message', {
  data() {
    return {
      message: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateMessageArray(newMessage) {
      this.message.push(newMessage);

      this.$nextTick(() => {
         // Scroll Down
      })
    }
  }
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `watch`?

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    messages: []
  },
  watch: {
    'messages': function (val, oldVal) {
      //Scroll to bottom
    },
  }
})
```

Edit: Please see the other answer, as this solution requires using the `nextTick` function to ensure the DOM is updated.

Comment: Huh, that actually works! I thought `watch` would only trigger when the variable changes, not after all the other callbacks. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea of how could i call a method of the vue instance from a watcher?

Comment: @SebastianHernandez Just use `this`