# Call function at end of v-for in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have  a v-for in my code that loads many svg's. The images are uploaded by the user in another page. To keep the proportion I had to create a javascript function to remove the width and heith of the svg's so the image will adapt to the parent element.

[image: Array of svg's]

On slower computers my js function is running before the v-for, so I created a setTimout function to wait for 100ms.

I would like to know if there is a way to run the function right after the v-for is completed.

Comment: This is XY problem. You don't have to be tied to v-for renders as they are internal mechanism. In this case you probably have to wrap svg with a component and make it affect its own child.

Comment: Have you tried attaching an index to the for loop (v-for='(val,index) in values') pass this into a function and have some condition where index === array.length-1 then execute the function

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808844/vue-js-event-after-v-for-is-done  @Eliu Moraes

Comment: I couldn't do it using EstusFlask  suggestion and initially adopted the way George proposed. It still worked only 30% of the time. The way I found to solve it was performing a regex when receiving the API data so when the VueJS loads the images it is already without the width and height. I dont know if $nextTick would solve the problem, but since it is working now I will keep regex as a solution.